# Will Containerization (Docker) replace Continuous Integration?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

Or, in other words, **Do "images" beat "scripts"?**

I am new to the Docker story, and unfortunately I am currently working in an environment where CI is not yet a reality ;-P

But, I have the following experience on "image" beating "script":

If I want to distribute, even only for exploration/training purpose, a (desktop) application for some of my colleagues, I have to go through a long and costly process, resulting in an installation **script** for the software to be installed on workstations. The end result being that the **script** takes quite some time to execute and can fail due to doggy context variations.

So, I did not do that. Instead, I have asked to test AWS and Google Cloud Platform ;-) Then, I have installed a virtual machine with the software I wanted to distribute, together with a clientless (HTML5) remote desktop gateway (e.g. [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/)), and I have taken an **image** of it.

THEN, when a colleague needs to try it, I can just create a new VM instance based on the image and it's done! It takes the time for the VM to be created (<30 sec), there is no installation script, no deployment-thingy!

The "image" won over the "script".

NOW, I am imagining doing the same kind of "short-cut" within our DevOps team. The developers might deliver a ready-to-run container, instead of a ready-to-be-built source-code. No?

And, why not going further... Why not testing (systematically) in PRODUCTION with a segmented small group of chosen users? If I have versioned containers that can run in parallel - the stable one together with the brand new one - and if I can "redirect" only a limited (chosen) subset of my users to the new one... Do I still need this internal-testing-phase-which-does-not-really-work?

Does this make sense? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: So far, it is the main aim of Docker. Not to "replace" but **ease** this step.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that Docker images will only run in a Linux 3.10+ kernel.
That kernel level is not always seen in an actual production server.

Most of the LTS (Long Term Support) distros running in production right now are RedHat or Suse which are still based on 2.6 or 3.0 kernels. The very latest versions are 3.1+ but are still being validated by our IT Unix team.

And of course, that applies only to program running on Linux. Maybe Solaris (although it has its own containarization system with global/local zones).
Not Windows yet.

Finally, the goal of a CI is to continuously deploy an image which is close to the production environment. If your prod is running a Suse distro, you don't have yet a Suse image (only OpenSuse 13+ ones). So you might not be able to achieve in an image the *exact* same environment as the one of your actual production server.

Conclusion: it won't replace but can complement a CI, as it (Docker-based CI) involves its own set of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no (IMHO, at least).

The uses and goals of containerisation and of CI are rather orthogonal/unrelated - hard to replace something when you're not doing what that something is doing ;)

The Containerisation technology can, at best, be seen as a possible way of performing only **some** types of testing, for software intended to be executed on containable environments.

Not all build/test environments are presently containable - there is no Universal Container technology (capable of running in a container **any** piece of software/firmware) in sight.

Some CI systems may involve multiple verification steps which wouldn't necessarily fit into a single container. While containerisation may help/play well with CI for execution of a particular verification step, CI/scripts will continue to exist outside/above containers, even if just to coordinate verification steps across multiple containers.

> Do "images" beat "scripts"?

Nope - images can't come into existance without scripts ;)

Switching to your more-specific subquestions...

In your case the "image" wins over the "script" only if the collegue wants to peek at **exactly** at your container contents (i.e. your changes on top of a certain label). Can't check your changes integrated with other changes or on top of other labels. Very limited (re)use IMHO.

Developer-supplied ready-to-run containers? How would a "PASS" in a test of such a container differ from a "but it builds OK in my workspace" argument?

Similarly - what would a successful result of the segmented testing of a new container side-by-side with the stable one mean? Nothing more than some (< 100%) level of confidence that it won't cause a breakage when the changes will finally be integrated into the branch (for which "ready-to-be-built source-code" will be required anyways, BTW).

Just in case it's not clear - this is not a limitation specific for containerized-based testing, it's just how verification in isolation works (script or image based, it doesn't matter) - results don't really mean much - they can easily go the other way when the code is actually integrated into the branch.

The CI verification is the meaningful one as it reflects the actually-integrated code context.